# C# WebDriver for Selenium - is there currently a way to set the setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer value

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Per this documentation: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/UntrustedSSLCertificates 
I'm simply wondering if there's a way to do this with the C# driver?

I tried:

```
firefoxProfile.SetPreference("assume_untrusted_certificate_issuer", false);
```

but that did not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that when you call this:

```
profile.SetPreference(preference, value)
```

you can only adjust the firefox preferences that appear when you type `about:config`
 in the firefox address bar.

---

You can accept untrusted certificates in C# like this:

```
profile.AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true;
```

Comment: I do have profile.AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true; but I am dealing with the edge case provided per the above link which states:"This could pose a problem for someone testing a site with a valid certificate that does not match the host name it's served from (e.g. test environment serving production certificates). An additional feature for FirefoxProfile was added: FirefoxProfile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer. Calling this function with false will turn the ERROR_UNTRUSTED bit off and allow a user to work in such situation."

Comment: I should note that I accepted this answer as the item regarding about:config explains the proper use of firefoxProfile.SetPreference(preference, value), but I'm still looking for a way to work around this edge case if anyone knows of a way to access the AssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer option via the C# driver.